# Differentiation on $(C[0,1], d_\infty)$ and $(C[0,1], d_1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Define $F:C[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $F(u)=\int_{0}^{1} (u(x))^2 dx$.

We have verified that directional derivative of $F$ at $u$ in direction $g$ is $D_gF(u)=\int_0^12u(x)g(x)dx$.

Now there is a claim that the differential of $F$ at $u$ is the same map $(F'(u))(v)= \int_0^12u(x)v(x)dx$, under both $d_1$ and $d_\infty$.

I use definition of differentiation, after several steps, I get

$\frac{|F(u+h)-F(u)-F'(u)(h)|}{\|h\|} = \frac{\int_0^1 (h(x))^2dx}{\|h\|}$

But downstairs is either a sup (in $d_\infty$) or an integral (in $d_1$), and I don't know how to continue to bound the expression to $0$ (as $h\rightarrow0$) in either case..

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
\|h\|_2 \le \|h\|_\infty^\frac{1}{2}\|h\|_1^\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
then it follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{\int^1_0 h(x)^2\ dx}{\|h\|_\infty} \le \|h\|_1
\end{align}
and likewise
\begin{align}
\frac{\int^1_0 h(x)^2\ dx}{\|h\|_1} \le \|h\|_\infty.
\end{align}

It remains to prove the first inequality. Observe
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 h(x)^2\ dx \le \|h\|_\infty \int^1_0 |h(x)|\ dx .
\end{align}